# HP Fortify: exitcode -12000

Tags: fortify

I'm using the latest version of HP Fortify Static Code Analyzer, 4.21. The batchfile "bin\**fortifyclient.bat**" with the argument **uploadFPR**, gives a "An unexpected error occurred" and the exitcode is **-12000**.

The uploadFPR has worked before (previous week) on the same computer with the same source.
So I don't know what is causing this error. I have tried to use a new AnalysisUploadToken, but that makes no difference.

I cannot find what this particular Fortify exit code -12000 means. Does anybody know what it means?

Comment: SSC would have logged additional information.  Check the servlet container's ssc.log.

Answer (score 1):

I hit this same error when I upgraded my SCA client.

**I believe the error indicates that the FPR file was generated with a version higher than the installed Fortify SSC server.**

After downgrading my client, and creating a new FPR file, it uploaded correctly.

**Update:** After more faults, it appears this error is more of a general processing fault of the FPR file. Your best bet is to look at the SSC server logs for processing exceptions that might reveal the reason the processing failed.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if the SCA and fortify utility share the same error code. For the sourceanalyzer, error [12000]=ASP/VBScript Translation Fidelity: ; Indicates how much of the classic asp and VBScript was translated successfully. Fix parse errors to increase.